# Why this line segment intersection algorithm not work?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I trying to calculate intersection point of two segments. Every segment will be either vertical or horizontal (0°, 90°, 180°, 270°). I need also calculate the intersection point if both segments are vertical or horizontal.

[image]

```
function intersection(line1, line2) {
    var origin1x = Math.min(line1.getStartPosition().x, line1.getEndPosition().x);
    var origin1y = Math.min(line1.getStartPosition().y, line1.getEndPosition().y);
    var origin2x = Math.min(line2.getStartPosition().x, line2.getEndPosition().x);
    var origin2y = Math.min(line2.getStartPosition().y, line2.getEndPosition().y);

    var dx = origin2x - origin1x;
    var dy = origin2y - origin1y;

    if((line1.isHorizontal() && (dx < 0 || dx > line2.getLength())) || (!line1.isHorizontal() && (dy < 0 || dy > line1.getLength()))) {
        return null;
    }

    return {
        x: line1.isHorizontal() ? origin1x + dx : origin1x,
        y: !line2.isHorizontal() ? origin2y - dy : origin2y
    }
}
```

The code works well in some cases, but sometimes fail.

For example:

```
line1 = ((0, 50), (0, 30)) // ((startX, startY), (endX, endY))
line2 = ((0, 0), (0, 30))
shouldBe = (0, 30)
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I need also calculate the intersection point if both segments are vertical or horizontal". You what? How can parallel lines intersect? ;-)

Comment: If both lines are horizontal or vertical, that means they're parallel. Which means they'll never intersect (Unless they're "following" each other, possibly: `-  -`)

Comment: One of the example lines should be horizontal, surely? e.g. (0,0), (-30, 0) ?

Comment: Bathsheba: I meant that if they have the same Y or X.

Comment: Your logic is quite flawed. In this case, `dy` becomes `-30`, which isn't very helpful at all. Why should the `Math.min` be helpful on the line endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your lines are always either horizontal or vertical, it follows that they're exactly equal to their axis-aligned bounding boxes.  Thus, instead of using a line intersection algorithm, we can simply use a bounding-box intersection algorithm, like this pseudocode:

```python
# get the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates of each region
# (this part can be skipped if you know the coordinates are sorted already)
(xmin1, xmax1) = sort(region1.start.x, region1.end.x)
(ymin1, ymax1) = sort(region1.start.y, region1.end.y)
(xmin2, xmax2) = sort(region2.start.x, region2.end.x)
(ymin2, ymax2) = sort(region2.start.y, region2.end.y)

# get the maximum of the minimums and the minimum of the maximums
xmin = max(xmin1, xmin2), xmax = min(xmax1, xmax2) 
ymin = max(ymin1, ymin2), ymax = min(ymax1, ymax2) 

# check if there is any overlap
if xmin > xmax or ymin > ymax:
    raise error("the regions do not intersect")
else:
    return new region( start=(xmin, ymin), end=(xmax, ymax) )
```

Note that this code returns a new bounding box that covers the entire area where the two regions overlap.  Even for regions that are horizontal / vertical lines, it's possible for this area to contain more than one point, if the two lines have the same orientation and overlap over a range of points.  If you need just one point, you can always e.g. pick the midpoint of the overlap area.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to solve this:

Write the equations of both lines using `y = m1x + c1` and `y = m2x + c2`.  Note the special cases: if a line is horizontal then it has the equation `y = c` and if vertical then it has the equation `x = c` (in this last case `c` is actually the interception point on the `x` axis but the algebra will still work out well).

Solve for the coefficients `m1` and `c1` using the supplied vertices for the first line and similarly for `m2` and `c2` using the vertices for the second line.

Once you have these equations, the intersection point is the solution of the two simultaneous equations that will give the values of `x` and `y` in terms of the computed coefficients.

Note that this will work for any non-parallel arrangement of the lines. (For the parallel case the simultaneous equations will be linear multiples of each other and so will not yield a solution.)

A bit of algebra but you should be able to chug thought it.

Comment: In this case, m will always be 0 or undefined.  Which will simplify the calculations, or cause them to be meaningless, depending on how careful you are with the algebra.

Comment: @Teepeemm: That's a good point. This answer would have been useless to the OP in its original form. Hope you approve of the edits.

Comment: I'm still not sure if it helps OP.  He's got lines by their endpoints, not their slope intercept form.  It seems like converting to slope intercept doesn't gain you anything except extra work.  In the end, everything will come down to finding the ordering of the endpoints, which I don't think will be substantially different than Ilmari Karonen's answer.